# Is the Hackage document building queue visible?

Tags: haskell, deployment, hackage, haddock

After uploading a new version of a Haskell package to Hackage, automatic document building can take some time, during with the package lacks online documentation. I'd prefer not to announce package changes until such documentation has been built.

Is there a way to view the Hackkage document building queue, or perhaps another method for estimating how long it will be until my documents will be built; or perhaps even a way to arrange notification?

---

Note, this is not a question about how to manually upload documentation. I know how to do that (and don't want to).

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but if you get your package added to Stackage, the docs are built with each Stackage Nightly build and can be accessed from stackage.org, e.g. https://www.stackage.org/package/wai

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to get notifications, but if you click the little "build log" link (e.g., https://hackage.haskell.org/package/connection-0.2.8/reports/ ) you'll get the list of build reports for the package.